# How pass data from Firebase iOS from a TableViewController to another ViewController

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I'm developing an app when I'm trying to find users by retrieving them nickname from Firebase Database during search in a search bar. I put all my users nickname in an array and show it in tableView when the tapped text match users nicknames with autocompletion. I'm able to do it.
But now I'm trying to display the user profile page if I search for a user, I select is name in the table view then tap his nickname on the tableView then it open another ViewController and should display the information of the user selected but it just show the default page without any custom informations about the selected user.

I show you my current code:

```
class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var userTab = [String]()
var userEmpty = ["No user"]
var filteredUsers = [String]()

var searchController: UISearchController!
var resultsController = UITableViewController()

var name: String!

var ref: DatabaseReference!
var dictDetails: [String:AnyObject]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "pseudo").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.userTab = []
        if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
            print("No data found")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let userSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let uid = userSnap.key
                let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let pseudo = userDict["pseudo"] as! String
                let total = snapshot.childrenCount
                self.userTab.append(pseudo)
                self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
                continue
            }
        }
    })

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.userTab.filter { (user:String) -> Bool in
        if user.lowercased().contains(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "userProfil" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let data = userTab[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
            let pseudo = data["pseudo"] as? String
            let controller = segue.destination as! UserViewController
            controller.pseudo = pseudo!
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        return self.userTab.count
    } else {
        return self.filteredUsers.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.userTab[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "userProfil", sender: nil)
}
}
```

And for the other view controller :

```
class UserViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
var pseudo: String = ""
var dictionary: [String:AnyObject]?
var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: pseudo).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.name.text = dictionary["pseudo"] as? String
        }
    })
}
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: what are you debugging results? when you place breakpoint inside callback you can print data from firebase?

Comment: Ok I resolve my issue, I can post the solution here

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue myself, I post the code if it can help someone else.

I show you my current code (first view controller is UserTableViewController) :

```
class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var userTab = [String]()
var userEmpty = ["No user"]
var filteredUsers = [String]()

var searchController: UISearchController!
var resultsController = UITableViewController()

var name: String!
var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "pseudo").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.userTab = []
        if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
            print("No data found")
        } else {
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let userSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let uid = userSnap.key
                let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let pseudo = userDict["pseudo"] as! String
                let total = snapshot.childrenCount
                self.userTab.append(pseudo)
                self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
                continue
            }
        }
    })

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.userTab.filter { (user:String) -> Bool in
        if user.lowercased().contains(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}

// I change the content of this function
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "userProfil" {
         let userViewController = segue.destination as! UserViewController
         userViewController.pseudo = self.name! // "name" is a String variable declared at the beginning, "pseudo" is a variable declared in the UserViewController
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        return self.userTab.count
    } else {
        return self.filteredUsers.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.userTab[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

// This function is the most important because after search a user in search bar, it display it in table view cell then you choose it so you go the UserViewController where you can see the username write on this user profile page, you got to write the performSegue at the end of this function if not it can't work because if you put the performSegue at the beginning it won't find the right username because the prepare for segue function will call before and we don't want our "name" variable is nil
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let post = filteredUsers[indexPath.row] as! String
    self.name = post
    print("name : \(name!)") // You can see in the console the name of the user you choose
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "userProfil", sender: nil)
}
}
```

And for the other view controller (UserViewController) :

```
class UserViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
var pseudo = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    name.text = pseudo // Here name is a Label, so I put the "pseudo" variable for display it in the "name" Label and it can show the right nickname of user you choose in the search bar
}
}
```

Hope it can help someone else.
Now I'm trying to show his user profile image in the same page.